# Deploying a Spring app to Weblogic with no web components - war, rar, or ejb?

Tags: java, spring, ejb, weblogic, war

I'm deploying a new Spring JMS application to Weblogic 11g.  What is the accepted way to deploy a Spring application with no web components to Weblogic?

Historically the apps I've been working on have used a WAR to load the application context.  This does not seem like an acceptable solution now since this new application does not have any web components.  Wrapping the deployment in an EJB does not seem acceptable either since Spring is supposed to be a replacement to EJB.  A RAR does not seem to fit either, since the new application is not supplying any resources to other applications.

What options do I have, what is the accepted deployment method here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually RAR archive is used for resources.

Firstly you should create the components of JMS in WebLogic side (JMS server, JMS module, JMS connection factory, queue or topic) that your application may use. When this components are integrated all that you need to create the EAR archive and deploy it. EAR can be created without any EJB modules.

Comment: So I can configure the weblogic-application.xml to bootstrap my Spring Context directly from a .jar?I could then configure lifecycle listeners.  This makes sense, I'll have to try it out.